# ImageView and TextView with Adaper

Tags: android, textview, imageview, adapter

Here is my `Lisview` Adapter code :

The problem is that the `Listview` is totally empty. The list which is in constructor of Adapter has correct values. I guess that the problem is in Adapter. I'm looking for any clues. I just added getItem method and still nothing.

Comment: Could you provide the code where you declare your adapter and assign it to your ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onCreate()` you set your `Adapter` with

```
lista_widoku.setAdapter(adapterK);
```

but there your `Adapter` is `null`. You need to set it *after* initializing your `Adapter`.

If you do this then please limit your code to those most relevant parts. This is way too much code to comb through.

Comment: Do you have an image in your `drawable` folder named `ivHand`? Also, have you checked in the graphical interface to make sure that it is showing in your `layout` before running?

Comment: Shouldn't it be, `viewHolder.ivHand.setImageResource(R.drawable.ivHand);`?

Comment: I've changed ivHand to ivhand everywhere and still no icon.

Comment: What is the name you gave the `drawable` in your `drawable` folder? Use that with the suggestion I gave in my previous comment

Comment: Like I said -> ivhand

Comment: Ok, but, like I said, if it is a `drawable` then it should be referenced with `R.id.drawable`

Comment: Dude! It works! Finally ! Thanks 4 all! You're so patient.. Damn man :D

Comment: Yes, its a major character flaw of mine. Anyway, glad its working. Although, I said that earlier so you could have saved us both half an hour of our time ;)

Comment: Now I know, but here is 2am and I'm so sleepy ;)